# Eclipse shortcut - generate some a method from some code

Tags: eclipse

is there a shortcut to generate a method, when selecting a piece of code in my program? Sth like encapsule code or sth like that. Does that exist in eclipse? I cannot find anything in the help section.

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: What kind of method do you want? Getters and setters? Can you elaborate more on the exact use case

Comment: @peeskillet No I just want to select a piece of code in my program and then generate a new method from that.

Comment: Do you mean: Selecting code -> Right click -> Refactor -> Extract Method?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Yes exactly that! Pls add it as answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move a code part to a method you have to do the following:

1. select the code which should be extracted
2. Right click and select: Refactor -> Extract Method
3. in the option window: enter a method name and click OK